# Why Bool(true) != Bool(true) in chisel3?

Tags: scala, chisel, chiseltest

If I run a scala console in my [sbt project](https://github.com/Martoni/CIC) and import chisel3 package like it:

```scala
$ sbt 
sbt:CIC> console
scala> import chisel3._
import chisel3._
scala>
```

Then if I declare two Bool variables, there are not equal :

```scala
scala> val value1 = true.B
value1: chisel3.Bool = Bool(true)

scala> val value2 = true.B
value2: chisel3.Bool = Bool(true)

scala> value1 == value2
res0: Boolean = false

scala> value1.==(value2)
res3: Boolean = false

scala> value1.`==`(value2)
res4: Boolean = false

scala> value1
res5: chisel3.Bool = Bool(true)

scala> value2
res6: chisel3.Bool = Bool(true)
```

Is it normal ?

Note: I tried to use the hardware equality `===` without success :

```scala
scala> value1 === value2
chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Error: Not in a UserModule. Likely cause: Missed Module() wrap, bare chisel API call, or attempting to construct hardware inside a BlackBox.
  at chisel3.internal.throwException$.apply(Error.scala:155)
  at chisel3.internal.Builder$.forcedUserModule(Builder.scala:494)
  at chisel3.internal.Builder$.pushOp(Builder.scala:558)
  at chisel3.Bits.compop(Bits.scala:206)
  at chisel3.UInt.do_$eq$eq$eq(Bits.scala:617)
  at .$anonfun$res1$2(<console>:17)
  at chisel3.internal.prefix$.apply(prefix.scala:49)
  at .$anonfun$res1$1(<console>:17)
  at chisel3.internal.plugin.package$.autoNameRecursively(package.scala:52)
  ... 31 elided

scala>
```

Is it a bug or a normal behavior ?

I need to compare some Bool() values in my tester2 testbench.

Comment: I think its pretty much the same reason that `Option(1) == Option(1)` returns false.

Comment: @sarveshseri and what is this reason?

Comment: I'm confused, `Option(1) == Option(1)` returns true: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PfJ2wqnZSp2jcT6md4svzA; however, using referential equality `Option(1) eq Option(1)` is indeed false because they are different objects, and the same thing applies in Chisel, I give a more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that while we *probably* should make equality work as one might expect for **literals**, it is not as clear cut a decision as one might think.

Thinking about Chisel's primary purpose as a hardware generator language, writing Chisel is fundamentally *metaprogramming* where we have to reason about two different phases: Chisel *elaboration time* (aka Scala run-time), and the actual hardware you're generating that is used in simulation and synthesis.

`==` returns a Scala `Boolean` so it only makes sense at elaboration time and means nothing to the resulting Verilog. Chisel provides `===` which returns a `chisel3.Bool` which is a hardware value that will show up in the Verilog.

Thinking in terms of `Wires` and `Regs`, `==` doesn't really make sense because these hardware components don't have statically knowable values during elaboration time. Thus in Chisel3, `==` is implemented a *referential equality*, ie. it is true only if the two objects are the exact same object.

Now as I said at the beginning, there is an argument that we should make `==` work for literals at least, even if it won't work for hardware components like `Wires`. It's not 100% clear if this is the right move because it could confuse people that sometimes they use `==` (only with literals) and sometimes they use `===` (with everything else). Because of testing libraries like `chiseltest`, I tend to agree that we should make `==` work for literals, but I just want to note that there is disagreement on this point.

Answer (score 4):

The solution I found to use equality is to use `.litValue`:

```scala
scala> value1.litValue == value2.litValue
res2: Boolean = true
```

But it remain a strange behavior.